# How can I pass a Laravel variable into my AngularJS view?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I am building a small photo application to learn AngularJS 1.3. I come from a PHP background so conceptually this is rather different for me :)

I'd like to pass a variable (the URL of my photos folder) into my AngularJS view (an .html file). How can I do this?

**In other words, what's the best practice for passing application constants from PHP to AngularJS ngRoute views?**

Here's the code:

## Laravel Controller Method

```
public function showHome()
{
    $upload_url = Config::get('app.url');
    return View::make('home')->with('upload_url', $upload_url."photos/");
}
```

## Blade Template

`$upload_url` is the variable I would like to use in my AngularJS view (`index.html`).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <title>Test Application</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">

        <div class="container">

            <p>The location of the photo files is:</p>
            <p>{{ $upload_url }}</p>

            <ng-view></ng-view>

        </div>

        {{ HTML::script('assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js') }}
        {{ HTML::script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js') }}
        {{ HTML::script('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js') }}
        {{ HTML::script('app/controllers/mainController.js') }}
        {{ HTML::script('app/services/photoService.js') }}
        {{ HTML::script('app/app.js') }}

    </body>
</html>
```

## App.js

```
var constantsHelper = {};

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'mainController', 'photoService']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/",
        {
            templateUrl: "app/views/home.html",
            controller: "mainController"
        }
    );
});
```

## Main Controller (mainController.js)

```
angular.module('mainController', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, Photo) {

    Photo.get()
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.photos = data;
        });

});
```

## Photo Service (photoService.js)

```
angular.module('photoService', [])

.factory('Photo', function($http) {

    return {

        // Get all the photos
        get : function() {
            return $http.get('/api/photos');
        }

    }

});
```

## ...and finally my Angular view (home.html)

I'd like to prefix `photo.filename` with the `$upload_url` value from my blade template (which comes from the `showHome()` method of my Laravel controller).

```
<div class="photo" ng-repeat="photo in photos">

   <div class='row'>
       <div class='col-md-10 col-md-offset-1'>
           <div class='loaded-image mb25'>
               <img src='{{ photo.filename }}'>
               <p>{{ photo.description }}</p>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

Thanks! Any pointers that can put me on the right path are appreciated :)

### Edit:

I have it working, but no idea if this is the best practice!

I've added this to the bottom of my blade template:

```
<script>
    constants = {};
    constants.upload_url = {{ $upload_url }}}";
</script>
```

And modified the main controller to pass the constants using `$scope`.

```
angular.module('mainController', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, Photo) {

    Photo.get()
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.photos    = data;
            $scope.constants = constants;
            console.log(constants);
        });

});
```

Then I can access the upload URL in `index.html` simply with `{{ constants.upload_url }}`.

So... it works but I have no idea of this is hacky or not ;)

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you already managed a replace for modifying either Laravel or Angular extrapolate syntax?

Comment: Hi Diego! Thanks for you reply :) I'm not sure I understand the question though, will the Blade and Angular extrapolate syntaxes ever conflict with each other?

Comment: They definitely might conflict, haven't you worked with extrapolation? It's quite the first example for Angular ... http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_examples.asp

See how Angular may use `{{` and `}}` too.

Comment: There are different workarounds for this issue. I offer one in my answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wonder whether this would be the best practice or not. However **If the value doesn't need to be secure**, one of the most simple way to pass constant values from server is something like this.

In html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _config = {
        key1: server_value1,
        key2: server_value2
    };
</script>
```

In angular module run method.

```
angular.module('yourapp', [])
    .run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.config = _config;
    });
```

In your controller.

```
console.log($scope.config);
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you managed to have Angular and Blade syntax in order? In my case I changed what Laravel uses for echoing variables and evaluating expressions
this way setting at *`routes.php`*:

```
Blade::setContentTags('[[', ']]');        // for variables and all things Blade
Blade::setEscapedContentTags(',.', '.,');   // for escaped data
```

I'm not sure about how a good practice is but time to time I set some `ng-init` directives this way:

**Blade template**

```
<div ng-controller="mainController" ng-init="constants={upload_url:'[[$upload_url]]'}">
  ...
</div>
```

**View**

The way I obtain a rendered view this way:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController" ng-init="constants={upload_url:'some_url_string'}">
 ...
</div>
```

Then you could reach it from a controller and use it for `ng-Route` this way:

```
$scope.constants.upload_url
```

Comment: You can do this at same place where you got any intended controller assignment, see my edits

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this, the same, I advise you to follow this pattern in order to set those "general and top level never changing variables you don't want to request later" at your top lever controller