# Migrating Laravel routing to Angular JS routing or workaround

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5, url-routing

I have a demo site running on Laravel as Back-end and Jquery on front and was attempting to migrate Jquery to Angular JS. 
I was trying to achieve this using Laravel as routing and as a service for AngularJS. But this way I can't get variables on through URI on Angular (at least I couldn't find any way). 
Example:

> http://localhost/estudio_php/user/perfil/1/edit

Angular Controller:

```
app.controller('estudioPerfilCtrl', function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi, estudioService) {
$scope.loading = true;

//Issue here, getEdit(1) to get data from id = 1, need to get URI variable value
estudioService.getEdit(1).then(function(response) {...}
```

Laravel Routing

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'estudio'), function(){

//auth
Route::group(array('middleware' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'ajax'), function(){
        Route::get ('{id}/edit',                    'Estudio\PerfilController@editAjax');
    });

    Route::get ('{id}/edit',                'Estudio\PerfilController@edit');
```

The `/ajax/edit` route feeds data to Angular Service, and the `/edit` loads Laravel view, that calls Angular Controller.

Should I migrate all routing to AngularJS? Or is there a work around for my problem?

Comment: The great thing about using Laravel routes is being able to apply middleware to some routes and not others.  If you did Angular routing your middleware would have to apply to every Angular route (assuming you would be doing a single-page angular application).  To answer your other question (workaround): way to pass URI variable to an Angular view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246298/how-can-i-pass-a-laravel-variable-into-my-angularjs-view